# Catalog search is not working properly

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Hi all I am Searching one product in search box but magneto will display Searching product as well as some other product. How to over come this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GO to the admin section System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search.
Select fulltext and save.

Then open file app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/Model/resources/Fulltext.php

and make changes in the code as follows:

```
$likeCond = '(' . join(' OR ', $like) . ')'; 
to
$likeCond = '(' . join(' AND', $like) . ')';

&

$where .= ($where ? ' OR ' : '') . $likeCond;
to
$where .= ($where ? ' AND ' : '') . $likeCond;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can change search options in the backend:

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog Search
```

You can choose `search type` as 'Like', 'Fulltext' and 'Combine', which are explained in more detail [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/search-type-like-full-text-or-combined).